# RichTextBox loses all the formatting when exporting to word

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, richtextbox

I copied word content to richtextbox without loosing format perfectly, but now I am editing the content in the richtextbox.

Now I want to export the richtextbox content to a word document without losing any formating, in C# using WinForms. How do you do it?

```
WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAsQuickStyleSet("abc.doc");

Range rng = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0);


for (int i = 0; i < _dgvrow.Cells.Count; ++i)
{
    // add code to loop thru controls and TypeText into word document

    Label lb  = (Label)this.Controls["lblfield" + (i+1).ToString()];
    rng.Text += lb.Text;
    rng.Select();

    Control ctrl = this.Controls["txtfield" + (i+1).ToString()];

    if(ctrl is RichTextBox)
    {
        RichTextBox rb = (RichTextBox)ctrl;
        rng.Text += rb.Text + Environment.NewLine;
        rng.Select();
    }
    else if (ctrl is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox rb = (TextBox)ctrl;
        rng.Text += rb.Text + Environment.NewLine;
        rng.Select();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `rb.Rtf` instead of `rb.Text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Text` property of a `RichTextBox` just returns plain text. Use the `Rtf` property to return rtf-formatted text.

Unfortunately, Word does not have a method for inserting RTF text. However you can paste RTF-text from the clipboard

```
Clipboard.SetText(rb.Rtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
rng.Paste()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the [rich text format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx) of your control, not just the [plain text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text.aspx).

Replace `rb.Text` with `rb.Rtf`.

From MSDN:

> The Text property does not return any information about the formatting applied to the contents of the RichTextBox. To get the rich text formatting (RTF) codes, use the Rtf property.

Additionally, if you want to [save the rich text format to a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), that's built in:

```
rb.SaveFile(yourFilePath);
```

Answer (score -2):

With running look over your say I can suggest which I coded correctly.

Save your coded rich text box with save file method as .rtf or .doc and then open in the microsoft word.

Will not fail.

with regards.

Comment: This was not an easy read... the first sentence is quite unreadable. I would edit it, but i don't know what you are trying to say....